# FFmpeg compile opus error

Tags: c++, compilation, ffmpeg

I'm following this tutorial to build FFmpeg statically (to not need DLLs) using Microsoft's compilers: http://cristobaldobranco.github.io/blog/2015/01/20/compiling-ffmpeg-with-windows-tools/

I'm however running into trouble when attempting to compile this:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "libavformat.a")
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

extern "C" {
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

int main() {
    av_register_all();
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to be able to find the header and library files, but I'm getting weird errors about opus:

[image: Opus error]

Here are my MSYS commands:

```
cd C:/Libs/ffmpeg
./configure --toolchain=msvc --arch=x86 --prefix=build/ --disable-network
make
make install
```

How do I get rid of these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opus uses some resampling features, so you need to link against libswresample.a when linking against libavcodec.a (which is used in libavformat.a).